# Grails File Upload + tagLib

Tags: grails

If I want to change create my Tag Library for file Upload via ajax, then what changes I have to make into  tag in grails.

I have code for file upload via ajax and using that I want to create tag library which upload file and also submit form through ajax...

what I have do for that??

Comment: Take a look at http://grails.org/doc/latest/ref/Command%20Line/create-tag-lib.html. You can also take a look at some existing plugins like remote paging to see tag libs are created. Hope that helps

Comment: tnx for reply but I want to prepare taglib! I know how to build it but I want to know how by code not by step,..... tnx in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have you run this command? This creates the necessary files and you just actually write code in those files. Bascially you just genereate HTML in those. Here is an example of a taglib http://www.howardism.org/Technical/Groovy/Useful_Taglibs.html

Hope this helps !!!

Comment: Here is a link to grails plugin which does the same thing http://www.grails.org/plugin/ajax-uploader